# How do I design thread-safety in the code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have few questions on below code:

1. How do I access class level map object from REST controller side. This object stores user input, so in controller side `map.get(<text>)` return count.
2. Do I still need thread safety from multiple threads using Lock or CountDownLatch in addText method?

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
       
public void addText(String text){
    System.out.println("current thread name "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    AtomicLong l = map.get(text);
    if(l == null){
        l = new AtomicLong(1);
        l = map.putIfAbsent(text, l);
        if(l != null){
            l.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }else{
        l.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might prefer using `#computeIfAbsent` over your manual null-check with `#get`. Then the entire block of code becomes one line: `map.computeIfAbsent(text, k -> new AtomicLong(1)).incrementAndGet();`

Comment: Actually, `map.computeIfAbsent(text, k -> new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet();`, to start at zero when `incrementAndGet()` is always called. But you don’t need an `AtomicLong` anyway for such a trivial case, e.g. using a `ConcurrentMap<String, Long>`, you can simply call `map.merge(text, 1L, Long::sum);`

Comment: Per @Rogue and @Holger above, `computeIfAbsent`, particularly on the `ConcurrentHashMap`, is great here because it should keep everything atomic.

Comment: Hi Guys , Thanks for your inputs ,can you please check my other 2 questions ?

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Every call to your Spring ApiRest controller will create a new instance of your object, so no concurrent access to your object.
2. If, for some reason your object is shared, static ..., your method: 'addText' doesn't have any side effect apart from mutating the map (which is concurrent friendly), so no more thread safety to add IMHO.

-- Edit to respond to comment --

- To keep in memory you can declare you map as static in some class or just declare it in your Rest Controller as class variable (as controllers are singletons by default if you don't *modify scope* )

Comment: 1) i want to keep map in memory regardless of number of requests , is it possible without cache or loading from persistence?

Comment: Spring does not create a new controller instance for each request.

Comment: @timmz, how to store that map using spring cache , i dont see any good example